# find the dimension of a linear transformation Kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

given $V$ a vector space, let $\dim{V}=n$.
 $T\colon V\longrightarrow V$ is a linear transformtion with $\dim(\operatorname{Im}{T})=r$.

Let $X$ be the set of all linear transformtion $F:V\longrightarrow V$ with $T\circ F=0$.

I need to prove that $X$ is a subspace of the space of all linear transformtion $V\longrightarrow V$ and find its dimension.

It's not a problem to prove that $X$ is a subspace of all the linear transformations $V\longrightarrow V$ as in fact $X=KerT\circ F$.

What I'm confused about is $\dim{X}$. Looks like it's $n-r=V-ImT$ but i'm not sure how to exacly explain this, as I don't know what is $KerF$ and don't know how to prove what is the dim of a LT composition.

Comment: Since $X$ is a set of linear transformation thus we need to define what we mean by $\dim(X)$.

Comment: $X$ is a subspace of $\operatorname{Hom}(V,V)$. In particular, $X$ is a vector space and has a well-defined dimension. There is no ambiguity on what we mean by $\dim{X}$

Comment: @Pedro Ok thanks for the clarification on that point.

Comment: @Pedro I don't understand why you are considering $n(n-r)$ as dimension and not $(n-r+1)^n$.

Comment: @gimusi I have given arguments for my answer. It is also a well known result, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2037879/178668). So I think you should instead be asking yourself why are you considering $(n-r+1)^{n}$ as the dimension: this doens't match with the well known result, doesn't match with the 2 examples we have already discussed and most importantly you haven't argued your answer, so we can't really argue much. You are counting some random set of maps. This set of maps isn't a basis of the space we are looking at, hence it doesn't compute the dimension

Comment: @Pedro Thanks, now it is clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) It doesn't make sense to say $X=\ker{T}\circ F$, because $X$ is the *set* of such maps $F$. I guess you meant that $X$ is the set of linear transformations $F$ that factor (uniquely) through the kernel of $T$. This is indeed the case by the universal property of the kernel. To show that $X$ is a subspace you must show that the zero map is in $X$ and that $X$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

2) We know that $\dim{\ker{T}}=n-r$. The maps in $X$ are in bijection with the linear maps from $V$ to $\ker{T}$. Hence we want to find the dimension of linear maps from $V\cong \mathbb{K}^{n}$ to $\ker{T}\cong \mathbb{K}^{n-r}$. The dimension of $X$ is therefore $n(n-r)$.

Comment: I also have some doubts with the interpretation of the OP. Why are you considering only bijection? I thought that the dimension would be $(n-r)^n$, I will check again my conclusion.

Comment: I don't think there is any doubt about the statement or about what the OP means. Why did you think that is the dimension? You didn't explain your reasoning and the conclusion which you got is wrong. Take $T=0$, then $X$ is the whole $\operatorname{Hom}(V,V)$ which has dimension $n^{2}$, not $n^{n}$

Comment: The reasoning is that we can map any basis vector in any basis vector of $ker(T)$ obtaining $(n-r)^n$ different maps. Is it wrong?

Comment: Yes: suppose the kernel had dimension 1 and V had dimension 2. You are claiming that there is only one map $V\to \ker$. There are infinitely many maps (if the field is infinite), so I assume you mean that $(n-r)^{n}$ is the dimension. But the dimension in this case is 2, not 1. A basis is given by the map sending the first basis vector of V to the only basis vector of the kernel and the other basis vector of V to zero, and the map sending the first basis vector of V to zero and the other basis vector of V to the only basis vector of the kernel

Comment: Yes I meant that the dimension is $(n-r)^n$. Thanks I will revise my answer.

Comment: What about $(n-r+1)^n$, indeed I forgot to consider the zero vector.

Comment: That answer still doesn't match with either of the two examples that we have already discussed, right? Your combinatorics are fine, but you have to compute the dimension, and for that you aren't counting the right set of maps. For example, in the last counting you did, $(n-r+1)^{n}$, you get a system of generators for the set of maps. But in fact, any such map can be expressed (uniquely) in terms of the $(n-r)n$ maps which send a basis element of $V$ to some basis element of $\ker$ and the rest of basis elements of $V$ to zero. So this is the set of maps that you should have counted

Comment: i still don't understand the answer. mostly because there's 2 different answers.

Comment: @Jneven there aren't two different answers. The other answer was wrong, as I pointed out and explained in the comments. If there is any particular detail you don't unserstand in this answer, I will try to clarify it

Comment: @Pedro Hi, I was reading this thread and was wondering why the maps in $X$ are in bijection with the maps from $V$ to $\ker T$? Thanks in advance!